# How do I get the intended output in C programming?

Tags: c

I want to write a code that calculates the laundry fare based on the weight of the laundry. I want it to stop after 4 inputs and calculate the total sales for that day. I can't seem to get the output printed properly, it keeps on printing 0 for all outputs.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    
    int main() 
{
      printf("\t\tWELCOME TO UNIMAP LAUNDRY");
      
     printf("\nThis program is to display laundry price paid by customers\n");

      float l, W, sum, r;

      for (l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
        printf("Please enter laundry weight(kg):");
        scanf("%f", & W);

        printf("Total amount to pay is RM%f\n", r);

        if (W < 1)
          r == (W * 1.2);
        else if (W < 7)
          r == (W * 0.9);
        else if (W < 12)
          r == (W * 0.6);
        else
          r == (W * 0.7);
      }

      sum += r;

      printf("The total sales are RM%f", sum);
      return 0;
    }
```

Example of the output I get:

```
WELCOME TO UNIMAP LAUNDRY
This program is to display laundry prices paid by customers
Please enter laundry weight(kg):12
The total amount to pay is RM0.000000
Please enter laundry weight(kg):6
The total amount to pay is RM0.000000
Please enter laundry weight(kg):5
The total amount to pay is RM0.000000
Please enter laundry weight(kg):9
The total amount to pay is RM0.000000
The total sales are RM-29726079709203136512.000000
```

Comment: Please indent your code so that it becomes readable.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and indent your code properly. It's very hard to work with unidented code, even for top programmers, let alone beginnrs. Also use meaningful variable names instead of `W`, `l` etc.

Comment: You may wish to move the line that prints "Total amount to pay" to the end of the loop; the `sum` variable should be initialized, `sum=0`, and the line `sum += r;` should probably be moved inside the loop, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` is a boolean operator,
`=` is assignment.

So instead of
`r == (W * 1.2);`
write
`r = (W * 1.2);`